# How to search in an array of objects, which can also have an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would like to use Ant Design breadcrumbs in a Gatsby project. Following [this example](https://ant.design/components/breadcrumb/#components-breadcrumb-demo-router-4) from the docs, I ended up with the following code:

```
const breadcrumbNameMap = {
  '/url1/': 'First page',
  '/url2/': 'Second page',
  '/faq/': 'Third page',
  '/faq/question1/': 'First question'
};

const pathSnippets = location.pathname.split('/').filter(i => i);
const extraBreadcrumbItems = pathSnippets.map((_, index) => {
  const url = `/${pathSnippets.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}/`;
  return (
    <Breadcrumb.Item key={url}>
      <Link to={url}>{breadcrumbNameMap[url]}</Link>
    </Breadcrumb.Item>
  );
});
const breadcrumbItems = [
  <Breadcrumb.Item key="home">
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </Breadcrumb.Item>,
].concat(extraBreadcrumbItems);
```

Then I can use `<Breadcrumb />` in my JSX like this:

```
<Breadcrumb>{breadcrumbItems}</Breadcrumb>
```

In order to use this component I need to define `breadcrumbNameMap`. There are a lot of pages on my site and I already have `menuLinks` in my `gatsby-config.js` (for header and footer navigation) as an array of objects, which can also have subitems as an array of objects, like this:

```
menuLinks: [
  {
    name: 'Services',
    url: '/tools/',
    subItems: [
      {
        name: 'Tool1',
        url: '/tool1/'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tool2',
        url: '/tool2/'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tool3',
        url: '/tool3/'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Blog',
    url: '/blog/'
  },
  {
    name: 'About',
    url: '/about/'
  },
  {
    name: 'Legal',
    url: '/legal/',
    subItems: [
      {
        name: 'Payment',
        url: '/legal/payment/'
      },
      {
        name: 'Privacy',
        url: '/legal/privacy/'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can get `data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks` with `graphql` and then get the link matching the url by this:

```
const link = data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks.find(item => item.url === url)
```

But how can I do the same for `subItems` array, nested in an object? Basically, I need to search though all objects at top level and in `subItems`.

Comment: data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks.find(item => item.subItems.find(subItem => subItem.url === url)))

Comment: @mkEagles This makes search only within `subItems`. I need to search both items and subItems at the same time